# Has anyone attempted to create a system which uses e style capabilities in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The object level capabilities that show up in E seem like an interesting addition to the Javascript language, especially considering the security issues that Javascript programs face. Has anyone tried implementing an object-capability type security system in Javascript, or by modifying a javascript VM?

Comment: May I ask what E reffers to? Is there some article I can read to understand what this question is about?

Comment: start at erights.org. E is a programming language that follows the capability security paradigm, but there are many other interesting things about the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Miller, the creator of E, is on the ECMAScript committee, and has been working very hard to ensure that ECMAScript 5/Strict is *almost* capability-safe, or, as he calls it "trivially securable".

He is currently working on [SES (Secure ECMAScript)](http://ES-Lab.GoogleCode.Com/), which is a capability-safe subset of ECMAScript, which, interestingly, can actually be implemented *within* ECMAScript 5/Strict itself. It basically consists of a small bootstrap script, which redefines some global objects and functions. Any code that is loaded *after* this bootstrap script has run, is guaranteed to be capability-safe.

They also have a superset of SES, called Dr. SES (Distributed Resilient Secure ECMAScript), which basically extends the capability-safety of SES into a distributed setting across multiple machines.

Previously, Mark Miller created [Caja](http://Google-Caja.GoogleCode.Com/). However, being based on ECMAScript 3, Caja is *much more* complex than SES or Dr. SES, because ES3 is *not* "trivially securable". In particular, Caja is a pretty complex compiler toolchain, which performs a whole-program-transformation and some quite sophisticated static analysis.

`initSES.js` is just a small script. The main difference is that there are some fundamental security flaws in ES3 which have been fixed in ES5/Strict. The main problem with ES5/Strict is ambient authority provided by the global object, but that can easily be remedied by simply removing or overwriting sensitive functions such as `eval`, which can be achieved with a simple bootstrap script such as the aforementioned `initSES.js` and does not require a transformation of the entire source program.

Answer (score 1):

Google **caja** is a pretty serious attempt: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

> [..] Caja provides a compiler (a "cajoler") that takes the web application and produces a "cajoled" HTML web application. The cajoler tries to verify security properties by doing static analysis, and where it cannot it rewrites the input to add runtime checks.